# Possible mistaken empty statement warning

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I've been having warning with all day with 
"If (Jtag.activeConnection);"
It gives me "Possible mistaken empty statement".
It doesn't effect my program but every video I've seen people never get that warning and I would like to just clear It.
The following is my code

```
public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    XRPC Jtag = new XRPC();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Jtag.Connect();
        if (Jtag.activeConnection) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing after your `if`. What are you trying to do in `button1_Click`?

Comment: if (Jtag.activeConnection) then what????

Comment: Button1_Click Is so my program can connect to my Modded Xbox. "If(Jtag.activeConnection);" Is the code for it to connect

Comment: It is not a error. Compiler just suggests that you made a mistake, because there is no sense in empty condition.

Comment: @Antrax , wow.. that's kind of unexpected.. but the snippet doesn't really depict that.. and considering this is a webform and you're contructing XRPC in the form.. you won't stay connected beyond the event being handled without some sort of loop occurring..

Comment: @BrettCaswell the question and the snippet was about the warning he was getting, not really about what the app is trying to do. Maybe it is still work in progress for example.

Comment: @FFMG, of course it is still a work in progress; I'm not sure you're following the context of the comments thus far.. I didn't ask anything about `button1_click`, or to what this app is doing.. I'm just responding to a comment with a comment.. and, if wanted to address the question/issue.. I would do so in an answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, your if statement is empty

```
if (Jtag.activeConnection) ;
```

So the compiler is asking you to confirm if that's really what you wanted to do.

Normally it should be something like

```
if (Jtag.activeConnection)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: that's a compiler warning eh?.. I can't say I've ever seen that one

Comment: Yes, 'Warning CS0642, "Possible mistaken empty statement"'

Comment: that's cool.. I suppose it's worth adding to the answer for completeness, eh?

Comment: @BrettCaswell add what? The OP asked about the warning he was getting and I explained why he was getting it.
There is no point in quoting the exact warning, just don't have empty conditional statements.

Comment: "add what".. the link, which provides a clear reason (worth quoting actually) to your answer, which is about the warning.. the reason for it.. and how to prevent it.. which again.. the content in that link addresses...

Comment: @BrettCaswell the warning was explained in my response, the warning number I gave was for VS2015, (and maybe for others), but it might be different for mono. But the warning will happen in just about any language I know. So the explanation, as simple as it seems, is all that is really needed.

Comment: fine.. I'll provide it then.. I think your reference to Mono compiler warnings is a good point, as well..

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving the compiler warning ([CS0642](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x19t380(v=vs.90).aspx))

because...

> A semicolon after a conditional statement may cause your code to execute differently than intended

It is a warning, and you can suppress it via compiler options, pragma directives, or correct it by providing a block to run your condition statements in.

I recommend the ladder; here is how that looks:

```
Jtag.Connect();
if (Jtag.activeConnection) 
{
    // by virtue of having the blocks, and removing the semi-colon.. the warning goes away.
}
```

Comment: You are assuming he received that warning, (and assuming he is using an MS compiler), I gave you that warning number when I explained to you that the compiler does give a warning when you have empty statements.
Maybe you need to add that your response is only based on other comments.

Comment: @FFMG, my answer isn't based on comments.. it's based on your refusal to provide a good, complete, documented answer.. despite citing the documentation and qualifying it with additional, noteworthy considerations in your commentary when prompted.. your answer is correct, but it's low-quality.. if you want to improve it with those additional considerations.. let me know.. I'll be happy to remove this redundent (yet currently necessary) answer..

Comment: Yes it was based on comments, I am the one who mentioned CS0642, not the OP, bto.rdz gave you the link, not the OP, because you didn't know about that warning until I mentioned it. So your reply is about a warning you didn't know about, not what the OP actually said/asked. Anyway, if you need help answering questions and/or C# I will be more than happy to help you, but this is not the place to do it.

Comment: @FFMG, not sure why I didn't respond to this at the time, probably because I was sick of the back and forth, as you were being in-comprehensive.. but as a lesson in cause and effect. where the effect being I posted an answer that contains information referenced from comments, the cause was not that the information was referenced in comments, it was that you were refusing to amend your answer to include cited material.

you provided 1 of the possible manner to "clear" the warning, where the other two explain why the people from the videos the OP referenced to were not getting it.

Comment: update your low-quality answer; don't jump on people for justifiably posting better answers when you refuse to do so.

and leave the pragmatic and best practice considerations in comments and code review.

Comment: @FFMG also, don't make false presumptions.. my initial comment to your answer was intended to invoke you to provide a more comprehensive answer, because I was and am quite familiar with compiler options, to include suppressing warnings.. which was clear to me at the point of reading that the people in the videos were never getting the warning.. which was the point of confusion for the OP.. the underline consideration in the question.. one that your answer.. in it's current form doesn't even address or elate to.. thus, low quality.

Comment: Even after a year, your comments are still wrong/misguided and you 'answer' is still invalid/wrong/misguided. Try and learn from your mistakes and move on, there is no shame is that. This section is not the right place for me to teach you how wrong you answer is.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have `;` at end of your statement. So just delete it.

Comment: That wasnt false. Just an another reason for this error.

Answer (score -2):

Both halves of this question still seem unanswered.

1) I don't know why he wants to accomplish this:

```
if (Jtag.activeConnection) {}
```

Maybe he just wants to get that expression evaluated (for its side-effect(s)). If so, I expect he could just do this instead:

```
Jtag.activeConnection;
```

Or, if that doesn't work, he could settle for doing this:

```
bool dummy = Jtag.activeConnection;
```

(Though one or both might provoke a warning about the unused result.)

2) About the "Possible mistaken empty statement" warning: Maybe he **prefers** to style his null `if` branches with `;`. Sometimes I might prefer `;` over `{ }` too, like this:

```
if (expression)
    ;
else
    ;
```

That seems legit, according to MSDN C# Language Specification. It compiles. But using an empty expression as an if- or else-branch provokes a compiler warning: "Possible mistaken empty statement" (CS0642). (It is bad style because the lone `;` is ambiguous.) (Sadly, there is no explicit, unambiguous `noop;` statement.)

I see no [intelligent] way to make the warning go away, for just those lines. Some IDEs have compact single-instance overrides for unwanted warnings (embedded in comment text at the end of the same line). VS2005 - VS2015 only offers that I can surround the offending line(s) with `#pragma warning disable 0642` and `#pragma warning restore 0642`, which is too ugly to contemplate. (I also refuse to use the #pragma or a compile option on the whole program - it is too risky. I want to suppress each specific warning individually.) ((**C++** offers `#pragma warning suppress`, which suppresses the specified error once (in the very next line) while only adding one ugly line. C# must have decided to never implement it.))

VS doesn't object if I style it this way (even though it does nothing), but I prefer not too. (It is too tall.)

```
if (expression)
{
}
else
{
}
```

And I don't want to say it this way either. (It is compact, but the standard automatic pretty-printing does not indent the `{ }` to where the `;` was, *even though i think it should*.)

```
if (expression)
{ }
else
{ }
```

Comment: @BrettCaswell: Convince me I shouldn't upvote it anyway.